# Android Default Button Click effect Is Not Shown

Tags: java, android, button, android-relativelayout, effect

I wanted to implement the android default button click effect on a Relativelayout. (The material design one)

But the problem is that it works on a view like TextView, But it's not working on a RelativeLayout(I want the relativelayout to have the android default button click effect , just like a normal button ).

I have used :

```
style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
```

and

```
style="?buttonStyle"
```

But none of them seem to work. They both work on a TextView but not on a Relativelayout. Any thoughts ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add this android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: It worked ! Thank you . Just post your comment as an answer so I can set it as the Best Answer.

Comment: Good. I added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your layout:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: There is something strange. When I am using this background  - selectableItemBackground - , elevation is completely disappeared and view.setElevation(); is not working. What can I do?

Comment: You had set anything to android:background before this change ? Post related code. .

Comment: I was able to make it work by wrapping the selectable RelativeLayout in another Relativelayout and added some elevation to the parent Relativelayout. Anyways, Thanks for your help. It is appreciated.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a not null `OnClickListener` to your `RelativeLayout`?

And make sure that the layout is clickable with (in xml):

```
android:clickable="true"
```

or, in code:

```
relativeLayout.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Give it a try with a simple OnClickListener

Comment: Ok. I will do so when i get on a PC. But there is something unusual. When I use "buttonStyle" , I can see the shadow that is in the default button click from api 21at the bottom of the relativelayout. But not the ripple effect itself. It is like that it is drawn behind the relativelayout.